# Get the value from radio button and pass it to controller (using PHP codeIgniter)

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

Here is the form for user to fill in:

```
<form action="/process" method="post>
    <div class="donationarea">
                <strong>I would like to adopt:*</strong>
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-check">
                       <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="squaremeter" value="1"> 
                       <label class="form-check-label">
                           1 m2 (€ 2,50)
                       </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                       <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="squaremeter" value="4">
                       <label class="form-check-label">
                           4 m2 (€ 10,-)
                       </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                       <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="squaremeter" value="10">
                       <label class="form-check-label">
                           10 m2 (€ 25,-)
                       </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                       <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="squaremeter" value="20">
                       <label class="form-check-label">
                           20 m2 (€ 50,-)
                       </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                       <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="squaremeter" value="other">
                       <label class="form-check-label">
                          Otherwise, namely (m2): <input type="text" name="squaremeter" placeholder="m2">
                       </label>
                    </div> 
                </fieldset>

            </div> 
</form>
```

After click submit button, here are the data returned from the form: 
[image]

We get every post data for the required input field except the first radio button which return empty string. Any hints?

Comment: do you put all this html code inside form or outside form?Because i am unable to see any form here?

Comment: or maybe the validation rule inside controller makes something strange, please show validation part of your controller.

Comment: what purpose this code serve.

 Otherwise, namely (m2): <input type="text" name="squaremeter" placeholder="m2">

missing the value parameter and may be in testing you are choosing it.

Answer (score 1):

Please check one radio button.
If you are not check any radio button then it comes blank in post.

may be it will help you.

Comment: I have already checked one radio button before sending the form.

Answer (score 0):

In Simple think you need to changes you Otherwise, namely (m2) input text name to name="squaremeter-1" then you will be get value

```
Array
(
    [squaremeter] => other
    [squaremeter-1] => 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is empty because you have a input text with the same name as radibuttons: squaremeter

Rename the input text to `squaremeter-other`.